# I need help to style a drop down menu

Tags: html, css

I've been making a calculator for my website and everything worked perfectly... until I viewed it in Safari.

In Chrome, my drop down menu had the correct styling as intended.
But in Safari, it seemed to lose almost all of it.

This is styling for the class "inputCalc", which is what the drop down menu's class is:

```
        .inputCalc{
            width: 60%;
            border: solid 2px black;
            padding: 10px;
            font-family: initial;
            font-size: 12px;
            font-weight: 500;
            letter-spacing: 2px;
            font-family: futura-pt;
        }
```

And this is the drop down menu:

```
<select class="inputCalc" id="ddm" onchange="areaUpdated()">
            <option value="mm">MILLIMETRES</option>
            <option value="cm">CENTIMETRES</option>
            <option value="inch">INCHES</option>
            <option value="m">METRES</option>
</select><br><br>
```

If you need more details about this issue then please tell me.

Also. The drop down menu isn't the same length as the input boxes, any reason to why that would be?
(I used this code `width: 60%;`)

Thanks in advance.

Below are two images that I hope make this a bit more easier to understand.
[image: Expected styling apart from the length]
[image: The problem I'm facing]

Comment: Please try doing a hard reload when doing it on safari, that is the issue sometimes

Comment: @khushi, what do you mean "hard reload?". I've view it on both my laptop and my phone and I'm still getting the same result.

Comment: There are a few standardized aspects to a select box, but the way they look is not one of them. Each browser sets its own default. If you don't want the default Safari select box the solution is to explicitly set all the css attributes yourself (or use a library). You have to explicitly set background, border, height, width, cursor, etc)

Comment: by hard reload, I mean, when you have the result on safari, long press the shift button while pressing the reload icon in your top search bar. This reloads the page with details that sometimes dont appear with a normal reload

Comment: @SydneyY, ok, I'll give that a go. Thanks

Comment: @SydneyY, sorry, that didn't seem to work

Comment: I'll jump on a computer and see what I can find out :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few standardized aspects to a select box, but the way they look is not one of them.

Technically HTML us just a markup language. Browsers add standardized JavaScript to certain elements like form and input, but that's an exception.

Each browser sets its own default styles. If you don't want the default Safari select box the solution is to explicitly set all the css attributes yourself (or use a library that does so).

You have to explicitly set background, border, height, width, cursor, etc to override the browser's stylesheet. I believe you also need to set the style of the option elements.

For example, this would make all select boxes look the same on chrome and on safari, I believe:

```
  <style>
    form select, form select:active {
      background-color:black;
      width:250px;
      height:30px;
      padding-left:15px;
      padding-right:5px;
      padding-top:5px;
      padding-bottom:5px;
      margin-top:50px;
      margin-bottom:50px;
      margin-left:auto;
      margin-right:auto;
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: darkslategrey;
      border-width: 2px;
      border-top-left-radius: 5px;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
      border-top-right-radius: 0px;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
      box-shadow: none;
      color:lightgrey;
      font-size: 14px;
      display:inline-block;
      position: relative;
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      appearance: none;
    }
    form select option {
      width:250px;
      height:30px;
      padding-left:15px;
      color:lightgrey;
      background-color: black;
      border-style: none;
      text-transform:uppercase;
    }
  </style>
<form>
  <select>
    <option>one</option>
    <option>two</option>
    <option>three</option>
    <option>four</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

[image: screenshot of my input next to a Safari-ish one]

This website has compiled some stylesheets that can help you test how things look in other browsers:

https://meiert.com/en/blog/user-agent-style-sheets/